# adding prefix string all tag in xml php

Tags: php, xml

Hello i trying to put prefix on my xml tags  like this

```
 <identifiant>
      <a:Nom>NOM</a:Nom>
      <a:NomJeuneFille i:nil="true" />
      <a:Prenom>PRENOM</a:Prenom>
</identifiant>
```

Who can help me

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Post your attempt, example data, expected output from that example data and what result you're currently getting. We're here to help you sort out issues with your code, but you still need to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an XML namespace prefix and it is invalid without a matching XML namespace definition. DOM has special methods to create XML nodes with namespaces:

```
// a list of namespaces just to avoid repeating the URIs
// the keys do not have to match the prefixes in the XML
$namespaces = [
  'xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
  'a' => 'urn:example:a',
  'i' => 'urn:example:i'
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
// the document element does not seem to have a namespace
$identifiant = $document->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('identifiant')
);
// add the namespace definition for prefix "a"
// namespace definition use a reserved, internal namespace
$identifiant->setAttributeNS($namespaces['xmlns'], 'xmlns:a', $namespaces['a']);

$identifiant->appendChild(
    // create an elment node with the namespace
    $document->createElementNS(
        $namespaces['a'],
        'a:Nom'
    )
)->textContent = 'NOM';

$identifiant
  ->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS(
        $namespaces['a'],
        'a:NomJeuneFille'
    )
  )
  ->setAttributeNS(
        $namespaces['i'],
        'i:nil',
        'true'
  );


$identifiant->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS(
        $namespaces['a'],
        'a:Prenom'
    )
)->textContent = 'PRENOM';

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<identifiant xmlns:a="urn:example:a">
  <a:Nom>NOM</a:Nom>
  <a:NomJeuneFille xmlns:i="urn:example:i" i:nil="true"/>
  <a:Prenom>PRENOM</a:Prenom>
</identifiant>
```

Namespace definitions will be added as required. You can avoid repeating it on sibling branches by defining it manually on an ancestor node. I did this for the "a" prefix, the definition for the "i" prefix was added automatically.

Comment: thank you but my XML elements are generated from json

Comment: That is not a reason against DOM. You are reading a data source (doesn't really matter if it is JSON or a Database) and create a specific XML output.

Answer (score 0):

Try find-and-replace on a selection (most text editors will allow you to do this)

If your file looks similar, you could replace the beginning blocks with minimal effort by abusing the idea that they will begin with spaces

- find       `<`
- replace       `<a:`

---

If this is not sufficient (ie. you have a more complex file or wish to do this for a great many files), you will want to reflow your XML document with an XML parser

A program would look something like

```
import XML parsing library
read XML file
iterate over the blocks of whatever depth until you find what you want
change the block names (perhaps copy to new blocks and switch 'em)
write the resulting file again (consider writing to a new file so you can compare them more easily)
```